# Get Filename with current date using regex

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, filenames, flowfile

I have a situation where I have to get a new file every day at a specific time which is saved automatically on a specific folder on a remote server using GETSFTP Processor.

for example today there will be a file created on a remote server named 20220223.csv (23rd of Feb current date). P.s I want to get only one file of the current date and I don't want to update my filename in the GETSFTP processor dynamically every day.

[image: this is my try but it gets all the files available.]

[image: NOTE: Expression Language is not supported.]

NOTE: Expression Language is not supported.

Comment: Try to set `Remote Path` to full file path - it supports nifi expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know the file name is `yyyyMMdd.csv' you don't need to use a file filter regex.

Instead, use an UpdateAttribute to set a `filename` attribute with `${now():toDate():format('yyyyMMdd')}.csv`.

In GetSFTP, set the`Remote Path` property to `/home/data/user/${filename}`.

Note: You could also combine that into just the GetSFTP with `Remote Path` set to `/home/data/user/${now():toDate():format('yyyyMMdd')}.csv`, I just like the readability of UpdateAttribute